# UIAlertController text alignment

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to change the alignment of the message displayed inside a UIAlertController on iOS 8?

I believe accessing the subviews and changing it for the UILabel is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 77):

I have successfully used the following, for both aligning and styling the text of UIAlertControllers:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "The message you want to display",
    attributes: [
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
    ]
)

myAlert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

You can do a similar thing with the title, if you use `"attributedTitle"`, instead of `"attributedMessage"`

### Swift 3 update

The above still works in Swift 3, but the code has to be slightly altered to this:

```
let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "The message you want to display",
    attributes: [
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black
    ]
)

myAlert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

### Swift 4 update

```
let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "The message you want to display",
    attributes: [
        NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body),
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
    ]
)

myAlert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

### Swift 5 update

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment
let messageText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "message",
    attributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.primaryText,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "name", size: size)
    ]
)

myAlert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Comment: Seems like this is private API use, did this make it into the App Store?

Comment: @powerj1984 yes, it did.

Comment: What's private about it?

Comment: Is there any objective-c version?

Comment: @SonicMaster sorry, but I don't have experience with Objective-C. I guess, since this is mainly assignments and calling functions, the translation should be straightforward.

Comment: I tried to see if this method works for changing text alignment when using `UIAlertAction` items in `UIAlertController` as well, but it resulted in some key-value compliance and undefined key exceptions and the controller not displaying.

Comment: Update for Swift 4                                                                                      let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alertMsg,
        attributes: [
            NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black
        ]
    )

Comment: Is there any documentation for keys like "attributedMessage" and "attributedTitle"? How will I get a list of all available keys?

Comment: @AkhilShrivastav google "UIAlertAction runtime headers", there are tons of undocumented keys that can be used to customize native components

Answer (score 11):

Use the below code

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:[title lowercaseString]
                                 message:[message lowercaseString]
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    if (alertStyle == kUIAlertStylePlainText)
    {
        [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

        }];
    }

    if (okTitle) {
        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[okTitle lowercaseString] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       callback(alert, action, nil);
                                                   }];
        [alert addAction:ok];
    }

    if (cancelTitle) {
        UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[cancelTitle lowercaseString] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                           callback(alert, nil, action);
                                                       }];
        [alert addAction:cancel];
    }


    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSMutableAttributedString *atrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[message lowercaseString] attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paraStyle,NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]}];

    [alert setValue:atrStr forKey:@"attributedMessage"];
    [viewInstance presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this is straight forward and does not seem too hacky, should be stable for a while

Answer (score 10):

I took up [@Amos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3260008/amos)'s answer and made it into a convenient extension:

```
public extension UIAlertController {

    func setMessageAlignment(_ alignment : NSTextAlignment) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment

        let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: self.message ?? "",
            attributes: [
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray
            ]
        )

        self.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    }
}
```

Then you can simply set the alignment value: `myAlert.setMessageAlignment(.left)`

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to subview tree until you get to the UILabels for the title and the message

```
NSArray *viewArray = [[[[[[[[[[[[alertController view] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews];
UILabel *alertTitle = viewArray[0]
UILabel *alertMessage = viewArray[1];
alertMessage.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

However, you may want to make an category for it

```
@interface UIAlertController (ShowMeTheLabels)

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel, *messageLabel;

@end

@implementation UIAlertController (ShowMeTheLabels)
@dynamic titleLabel;
@dynamic messageLabel;

- (NSArray *)viewArray:(UIView *)root {
    NSLog(@"%@", root.subviews);
    static NSArray *_subviews = nil;
    _subviews = nil;
    for (UIView *v in root.subviews) {
        if (_subviews) {
            break;
        }
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            _subviews = root.subviews;
            return _subviews;
        }
        [self viewArray:v];
    }
    return _subviews;
}

- (UILabel *)titleLabel {
    return [self viewArray:self.view][0];
}

- (UILabel *)messageLabel {
    return [self viewArray:self.view][1];
}

@end
```

Then you can align the text like this

```
yourAlertController.messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: `NSArray *viewArray = [[[[[[[[[[[[alertController view] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews];` That takes the cake for most nested ObjC I've never seen o.0

Comment: Yes. Apple doesn't really want people to mess with it.  It's is a far better investment to make a custom pop up alert than to tinker with something so deeply nested.

Comment: They never did come through with their promise, in one of the 2013 sessions they mentioned that they added a UIView property so that we could put whatever we want in there... It never made it in.

Comment: Actually this is the correct modern answer for the current API I guess!
It works like a charm! Sweet! Thanks man!

Comment: Has someone make it to the app store?

Comment: It crashes on iOS 11 (tested on real device): 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTextAlignment:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2** + **multiline string linebreak indentation**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle

paragraphStyle.headIndent = 14

let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "... multiline string need linebreak indentation ...",
    attributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray
    ]
)

alert.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following method will set the text alignment, while preserving the default font size.

```
static void makeAlertControllerLeftAligned( UIAlertController* avc )
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    NSMutableAttributedString *atrStr =
        [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:avc.message attributes:@{
             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paraStyle,
             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleFootnote],
         }]
         autorelease];
    [avc setValue:atrStr forKey:@"attributedMessage"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that some answers used a private API, which is not secure. I have a safer and simpler approach to achieve the same goal. Here is the code:

```
public extension UIAlertController {

    func demo() {
        title = "My Title"
        message = "My subtitle\nsecond line\nthird line"
        let messageLabel = findMessageLabel()
        messageLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    }

    func findMessageLabel() -> UILabel? {
        let originMessage = self.message
        let secret = UUID().uuidString
        self.message = secret
        let resultLabel = findMessageLabel(in: view, secret: secret)
        self.message = originMessage
        return resultLabel
    }

    private func findMessageLabel(in targetView: UIView, secret: String) -> UILabel? {
        if let label = targetView as? UILabel, label.text == secret {
            return label
        }
        for subview in targetView.subviews {
            if let label = findMessageLabel(in: subview, secret: secret) {
                return label
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This property](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/textFields) exposes the text fields, so could probably be used to configure them:

> **textFields**
>
> The array of text fields displayed by the alert. (read-only)
>
> **Declaration**
>
> *SWIFT*
>
> ```
> var textFields: [AnyObject]? { get }
> ```
>
> *OBJECTIVE-C*
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *textFields
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Use this
>   property to access the text fields displayed by the alert. The text
>   fields are in the order in which you added them to the alert
>   controller. This order also corresponds to the order in which they are
>   displayed in the alert.

Note: even though it says the property is `readonly`, it returns an array of text field object references which can be used to modify the controls.

Comment: Aren't those just the UITextFields that you can add to the UIAlertController? I only display a text through the message property that is styled as a bullet list and thus would benefit from being left aligned.

Comment: @DominikKaisers Yeah you are right; perhaps you can use the text fields and not use the message property?

Comment: Yeah, that probably would be a workaround. I'll give it a try, if nobody has an easier way.

Comment: These are the text input fields, not the message.

Answer (score -1):

```
yourAlertController.messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.