# NSTextAlignmentLeft for UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

Has anyone been able to find a way to set the text alignment of the `UIAlertController`. More specifically, the action sheet style?

I am using this method to add pictures (icons) to the actions :

```
UIImage *qsimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"snapshot.png"];
[snapshot setValue:qsimage forKey:@"image"];
//where 'snapshot' is a UIAlertAction
```

This works just fine, no worries, but when adding multiple actions to the controller all the text is centered but the images are left aligned creating an awkward UI experience.

I'm trying to resemble what Apple has done in the soon to be iOS 8.4 for their Music app:

[image: pic1]

Thoughts? Am I missing something simple?

**edit**

After doing some debugging I've realized the Alert Actions are in a UICollectionView. I can successfully change the colors of all the buttons, but can't alter the labels of the actions in terms of alignment. Here is how I accessed them:

```
 [[UICollectionView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

I also tried using setTitleTextAttributes on the actions with NSDictionary  objects and keys with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to loop through subviews to get UILabel and then you change alignment. Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962559/uialertcontroller-text-alignment

Comment: That is for the message and title of the alert not the actions.

Comment: Hi, can give source code of exact view ?

Comment: excuse me, can i ask how can you make alignment left for label in alert action like that?

Answer (score 3):

This is tested and working - UILabel+Appearance.h:

```
@interface UILabel (FontAppearance)
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTextAlignment appearanceAlignment UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end


@implementation UILabel (FontAppearance)

-(void)setAppearanceAlignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment {
    [self setTextAlignment:alignment];
}

-(NSTextAlignment)appearanceAlignment {
    return self.textAlignment;
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
UILabel * appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil];
[appearanceLabel setAppearanceAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```