# In iOS UIAlertController, Can we left align text of UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, text, alignment, uialertaction

I Need to implement a UIAlertController such as this `UIAlertController` with left alligned `UIAlertAction`

[image: description1]

After searching quite a lot in the internet and here in stackoverflow, I was able to achieve left aligned title of `UIAlertController`

[image: description2]

But how to left align text of UIAlertAction ?

Any help/clue would be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962559/uialertcontroller-text-alignment)

Comment: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview  Use this github source.

Comment: Any Success, i want to need this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with the following

```
[(your uialertaction object) setValue:@0 forKey:@"titleTextAlignment"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a newer question regarding the same thing at:

[UIAlertAction Text Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370823/uialertaction-button-text-alignment-left).

I was searching for the same thing and from what I have learned, you can only change text styling and alignment when you're using a UIAlertController in the `.alert` presentation style, but not when you're using it with UIAlertAction items in `.actionSheet` presentation style.

Only recourse here seems to be using libraries that provide custom implementations such as [XLActionController](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController).

Modifying text alignment for the UIAlertController as a whole in `.alert` presentation style is answered at: [UIAlertController Text Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962559/uialertcontroller-text-alignment).

I tried to use the same method for `UIAlertAction` but that resulted in some `Key-Value compliance / Undefined key` exceptions and the controller not displaying.