# In iOS UIAlertController, How to left alignment text of UIAlertaction

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I Need to implement a UIAlertController such as this UIAlertController with left alligned UIAlertAction. Any Workaround on this text alignment using UIAlertController

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to do this aside from using private APIs.

Comment: You can find the same answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962559/uialertcontroller-text-alignment/26949674#26949674